# std::map where key's are dynamic or string literal

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, stdmap

I have been tackeling this for the last day and I am still lost to a solution to the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<char *, char *> ourmap;
    std::map<char *, char *>::iterator ourmap_it;

    ourmap["hello"] = "world";
    ourmap["hello"] = "earth";

    char * key = new char[5];
    key[0] = 'h';
    key[1] = 'e';
    key[2] = 'l';
    key[3] = 'l';
    key[4] = 'o';

    char * key_other = new char[5];
    key_other[0] = 'h';
    key_other[1] = 'e';
    key_other[2] = 'l';
    key_other[3] = 'l';
    key_other[4] = 'o';

    ourmap[key] = "venus";
    ourmap[key] = "mars";
    ourmap[key_other] = "jupiter";

    for (ourmap_it = ourmap.begin(); ourmap_it != ourmap.end(); ++ourmap_it)
    {
        printf("map[%s] %s\n", ourmap_it->first, ourmap_it->second);
    }

    ourmap.clear();
    delete key;
    delete key_other;

    return 0;
}
```

The keys are not being overwritten, same behaviour if you do a `find`, on dynamic keys. The output explains a bit more in detail

```
map[hello] earth
map[hello] mars
map[hello] jupiter
```

### Question 1

Why does a `map` not `find` different the two values equivalent, in the case of `const char *` with `@key` and `@key` with `@key_other`.

---

### Question 2

Shall I be using a different container? or using different code (defining variables differently).

---

In the above code using dynamic keys does not make sence, but my actual code requires dynamic keys if the key values are read from a file as appose to defined in code, And as i don't know the size of the key in a given file, it has to be dynamic. The problem is although I can set the keys I can't retrieve the values back.

I was thinking of creating a my own find which does a `strcmp` on keys to figure out equivalence, but this seems hackey, so just consulting `SO` before I bodge it.

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: You're storing pointers - the uniqueness of the keys is based on pointer values, not on what they point to.

Comment: Exactly what jrok said. In your map you are storing pointers as keys. These pointers are all different, even though they point to identical character arrays.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay. Some thoughts.

1. You're causing some undefined behavior. You allocate 5 bytes for a string, and you put in that memory `"hello"`, but you don't have enough room to null terminate it. The undefined behavior happens when you try to print it.
2. You are not guaranteed that 2 instances of the string literal `"hello"` have the same pointer. The standard leaves that option up to the implementation.
3. I would solve most of your problems by using a `std::string` instead of a `char *`.

---

Let's fix some bugs in your code, and continue to talk about it:

```
int main() {
    std::map<char const *, char const *> ourmap;
    std::map<char const *, char const *>::iterator ourmap_it;

    ourmap["hello"] = "world";  // (1)
    ourmap["hello"] = "earth";  // (2)

    char * key = new char[6];
    key[0] = 'h';
    key[1] = 'e';
    key[2] = 'l';
    key[3] = 'l';
    key[4] = 'o';
    key[5] = '\0';

    char * key_other = new char[6];
    key_other[0] = 'h';
    key_other[1] = 'e';
    key_other[2] = 'l';
    key_other[3] = 'l';
    key_other[4] = 'o';
    key_other[5] = '\0';

    ourmap[key] = "venus"; // (3)
    ourmap[key] = "mars";  // (4)
    ourmap[key_other] = "jupiter"; // (5)

    for (ourmap_it = ourmap.begin(); ourmap_it != ourmap.end(); ++ourmap_it)
        printf("map[%s] %s\n", ourmap_it->first, ourmap_it->second);
}
```

I've referenced 4 locations in the code. What do we know about those keys.

Well, we know that `(2) != (3) != (5)`. But what cane we infer about `(1) ?= (2)`. Well, normally, (1) and (2) would be different. However, the standard **allows (but does not require)** a compiler to merge those two string literals to save memory. That being said, most compilers do this, especially within one compilation unit.

**So, let's assume that optimization happens.**

So, let's run step 1. Our map now looks like:

```
"hello" (1) => "world"
```

Let's run step 2.

```
 "hello" (1) => "earth"
```

Note that we still only have one element in the map, because `(1) == (2)`.

Let's run step 3.

```
 "hello" (1) => "earth"
 "hello" (3) => "venus"
```

We now have two elements in the map, because we have used **two** different pointers as our key.

I'm going to stop here, but I think this makes it clear.

---

Alternatively, we could use a std::string.

```
int main() {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> ourmap;
    std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator ourmap_it;

    ourmap["hello"] = "world";
    ourmap["hello"] = "earth";

    char * key = new char[6];
    key[0] = 'h';
    key[1] = 'e';
    key[2] = 'l';
    key[3] = 'l';
    key[4] = 'o';
    key[5] = '\0';

    char * key_other = new char[6];
    key_other[0] = 'h';
    key_other[1] = 'e';
    key_other[2] = 'l';
    key_other[3] = 'l';
    key_other[4] = 'o';
    key_other[5] = '\0';

    ourmap[key] = "venus";
    ourmap[key] = "mars";
    ourmap[key_other] = "jupiter";

    for (ourmap_it = ourmap.begin(); ourmap_it != ourmap.end(); ++ourmap_it)
        printf("map[%s] %s\n", ourmap_it->first.c_str(), ourmap_it->second.c_str());
}
```

Here, the output is:

```
map[hello] jupiter
```

This is because std::string implements `<` differently than a `char *`. It compares the contents of a string.

---

And just to expand on one last thing. Here's an example of the comparator being implemented.

```
struct comparator {
    bool operator()(const char * lhs, const char * rhs) const {
        return strcmp(lhs, rhs) < 0;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::map<char const *, char const *, comparator> ourmap;
    std::map<char const *, char const *, comparator>::iterator ourmap_it;
...
```

In this case, just like a std::string, we would see the following output:

```
map[hello] jupiter
```

Comment: on 2. are the pointer for the string literals irrelevant, as the map overwrites "world" with "earth", That seems correct behaviour to me. its when I start creating dynamic keys, that the map object does not relate the two as the same value.

Comment: @Angel.King.47: By the standard, `map["hello"] = "a"; map["hello"] = "b"` can insert one or two elements into the map. Both are legal.

Comment: Are you aware what the default comparator for a map is doing? It takes your two pointers and does a `<` on them. This does NOT compare the string, it compares the location in memory of the string.

Comment: So the "hello" literal string is being compiled into one memory location I assume.

Comment: Hey that helps like a charm, Thanks for the edit. I am just trying to get my head around the whole thing. The good point that you make is `std::string implements < differently than a char *` I believe that is exactly what I was looking at. oh and yes you are correct about the \0 as the end char *, forgot about that. Thanks

Comment: @Angel.King.47: Glad to help. But note, that using a std::string is not the only way to get that behavior. You could also implement the comparator differently. I've added a short example of that as well.

Comment: oh wow, did not know about the comparator, I would so give you +100 for that :D